# What is the best practice for comparing a value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Normally, I compare a boolean value by simply putting it in `if` statement as following:

```
var foo = 'Foo data';
if ( foo ) {
    // Do somethings
}
```

Recently, I just saw some people convert the variable to boolean before comparing it:

```
if ( !!foo ) { 
    // Do somethings
}
```

Is there any different in term of performance or advantage? Which one is more preferable?

Comment: Just how you want it ...  [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) ..

Comment: [This blog post](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) seems relevant and helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no functional difference in comparison, as seen in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aeujgovd/1

```
if(foo){}
if(!!foo){}
```

The only reason to use !! is to coerce a boolean value from a truthy/falsey value for example, if your API is expecting a proper boolean rather than a flag like 0 or 1.

```
var myObj = {flag: 0};
function submitObj(myObj){
    myObj.flag = !!myObj.flag;
    // ... Ajax submit
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the section 12.5 of the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5):

> ## 12.5 The `if` Statement
>
> ...
>
> The production IfStatement : `if ( Expression )` Statement is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `exprRef` be the result of evaluating Expression.
> 2. If `ToBoolean(GetValue(exprRef))` is `false`, return `(normal, empty, empty)`.
> 3. Return the result of evaluating Statement.

From this we can see that `ToBoolean()` is used on the passed in expression regardless of whether it's already a Boolean value or not.

Because of this I'm going to say that it's very unlikely that `if (foo)` will cause any more of a performance hit than `if (!!foo)`, and that the two extra bytes caused by the two `!` characters in your JavaScript file would probably outweigh any bonus from converting the value to a Boolean within the `if` statement anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid conversion ... it's always better in terms of performance. 
If all you want to achieve is to check if foo is null, I would choose the first option.